# Android RecyclerView doesn't respond to a click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I could display a list of items using RecyclerView + CardView. Now the issue is the RecyclerView doesn't respond when clicked. I used similar way on another app and it works fine. Not sure why it doesn't work on this case.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TrainingAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recView;
    ArrayList<Training> trainingList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.training_list_view);
        recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        trainingList = new ArrayList<Training>();

        /* do some processings to populate trainingList here
        for (int x = 0; ....)
            trainingList.add(new Training(..,..,..));

        /*

        adapter = new TrainingAdapter(trainingList);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Awesome dude!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        recView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**ClickListener.java**

```
public interface ClickListener {

    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);

}
```

**TrainingAdapter.java**

```
public class TrainingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrainingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Training> trainingList;
    static ClickListener mListener;

    public TrainingAdapter(ArrayList<Training> list){
        trainingList = list;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener cl){
        TrainingAdapter.mListener = cl;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Training trn = trainingList.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(trn.getEventName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(trn.getEventDescription());
        holder.tvDate.setText("Date: "+trn.getEventDate());
        holder.tvVenue.setText("Location: "+trn.getEventVenue());
        holder.tvType.setText("Event Type: Training");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (trainingList != null) return trainingList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvDescription;
        private TextView tvDate;
        private TextView tvVenue;
        private TextView tvType;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventName);
            tvDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventDescription);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventDate);
            tvVenue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventVenue);
            tvType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: You've not set the `ViewHolder` as the `OnClickListener` or the `OnLongClickListener` on anything; e.g., `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`, in its constructor.

Comment: Also, you might want to `return true;` from `onLongClick()`, unless you want the `OnClickListener` to fire, too.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `ViewHolder` class to below by registering click events with `itemView`

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvDescription;
        private TextView tvDate;
        private TextView tvVenue;
        private TextView tvType;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventName);
            tvDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventDescription);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventDate);
            tvVenue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventVenue);
            tvType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEventType);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this); //add this two lines
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            return true;
        }
    }
```